# need to change image in datalist on link click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a datalist that has an image with a hyperlink next to it. I need the hyperlink to change the image when clicked. I've already got the image to change when clicked, but I'm not sure how to get the image changed on hyperlink click. I don't know where to start.

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" Height="350px">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton style="padding:0;margin:0;" ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/add.png" OnCommand="ImgList_Command" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="FoodLink_Click"><asp:Label ID="Long_DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Long_Desc") %>' style="line-height:32px;vertical-align: top;height:32px;" Font-Size="Small" /></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
<SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DataList>
```

On the backend I only have:

```
protected void FoodLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.Visible = true;
    tof.Visible = true;
}

protected void ImgList_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl = "~/Images/removefood.png";
}
```

I don't know where to start. I assume I need to use another command, but how do I get the right image id?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you will need to establish a common element between the image and link buttons (I am assuming that you are trying to get the same effect on link button click as on image button click).

First and simplest thing that comes to mind is adopting a naming convention for the two related buttons. Eg, imageBtnX would work with linkBtnX and imageBtnY would work with linkBtnY.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did it; I got the clientid number from the linkbutton and set the property on the image button using that.

Of course the code needs cleaning and check to make sure it's an integer so it doesn't throw an error, but it works.

```
protected void FoodLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.Visible = true;
    tof.Visible = true;
    string indexnu = ((LinkButton)sender).ClientID.ToString();
    int gnum = Convert.ToInt16(indexnu.Substring(indexnu.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, indexnu.Length - indexnu.LastIndexOf("_") - 1));

    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)DataList1.Items[gnum].FindControl("btnAdd");
    imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/images/removefood.png";

}
```